# Astronomical software casa calls the plotms to display the Qt：Session management error

Tags: casa

Astronomical software casa calls plotms to display the error of Qt: Session management error: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported plotms did not responded to ping... [] restarting...

I could see the plotms interface, but the restart and keep displaying the error.

Thank you very much for your reading

I do not have any clue, I saw on the Internet said not under root users, but I am open casa under non-root users.

This puzzles me

Answer (score 1):

Well, linux cannot install casa versions above 6.0,and incompatible issues.The 5.8 casa problem was solved.